# nginx serves index.php instead of executing it

Tags: php, windows, nginx, fastcgi

I've setup nginx configuration to run php with fcgi on Windows. Here is my config:

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 8888;
    server_name api.domain.local;

    root        /projects/domain.server.new/app/rest/web;
    index       index.php;

    error_log   /webservers/nginx/logs/api.domain.local.error.log;

    location / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    #uncomment to avoid processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii
    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ //.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I've checked if fcgi server is running and it's all OK:

```
E:\Webservers\Nginx>netstat -aon | findstr :9123
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9123         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2644
```

Then I request the file using `curl` to prevent file caching:

```
$ curl -i localhost:8888

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.1
Date: Sun, 08 Nov 2015 09:15:20 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 960
Last-Modified: Tue, 27 Oct 2015 17:33:50 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "562fb57e-3c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

And it outputs files content instead of running it. I've tried several solutions offered in other topics:

1. Changed `default_type  application/octet-stream` to `default_type  text/html` in the config
2. Changed `location ~ / .php$` to `location ~* / .php$`

But it doesn't work. How can I debug it?

Answer (score 1):

The

```
location ~ /.php$ {
```

configuration line does not look correct. It means: a location that ends with a `/` character followed by any character followed by `php`. Eg: `foobar/zphp`.

What you meant probably is

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

which means: a location that ends with `.php`. Eg: `/index.php`

The same fix would be applied to the other section where you also confused the `\` with `/`.

Comment: thanks, I've updated the config in my question with fixes, but the file is still returned. Can you please take a look if anything else is missing?

Comment: @Maximus you have weird `*` after `~` in the corresponding line. Not even sure it makes sense there.

Comment: @Maximus just follow some article then. Remove anything extra and follow http://blog.chrismeller.com/configuring-and-optimizing-php-fpm-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-or-debian

Comment: @Maximus btw, do you restart nginx every time you change the config?

Comment: yes, sure, I do `nginx -s reload`. Thanks, I'll follow the article instructions then

Answer (score 0):

for run nginx in windows for php project and run index.php files by default you can add this code to

`/NGINX_FOLDER/conf/nginx.conf`

code:

```
http{
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            include fastcgi.conf;
        }
    }
}
```

80 is my default nginx port and 9000 is my tcp socket port, you can change it Suitable for your situation.❤